# codeanywhere search through multiple files content

Tags: web-development

Im thinking to use codeanywhere on my laptop.
Currently im using dreamweaver on my desktop and it has a feature to search through all files for a string i.e. i want to fine all files that call a certain function.

is there a way to do that in codeanywhere?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://support.codeanywhere.com/entries/25038222-2-7-Searching-and-Replacing-in-Files) may be relevant to you (the section entitled: **GoTo (Find in Files)**)

> In order to search across a set of files, you'll want to use the Goto
>   Files feature. Here, you can search of a string or regular expression,
>   within your entire File Explorer. You can also filter based on
>   extensions, like .html or .php. It is located on top of File Explorer
>   and is represented by magnifying glass icon and the "Goto Files" text.

Comment: i dont seem to have that option for some reason:

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/YdHQcIy.png

Comment: @Andrew Not sure - may be worth trying to contact them directly as this is from their documentation. I just checked and I too do not have it and can't see a way to find it.

Comment: ok thanks, at least i know its not just my account

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround the problem by doing a search at the SSH Terminal: 
`grep -rnw -e "you search text"`